# gradle using ReplaceTokens where replace tokens are dynamic

Tags: gradle, groovy

I've been googling a bit but I'm not sure if what I want to do can be done.
I'm using gradle and I have a couple of template files containing some configurations.
I want to have a task that can basically replace this files containing tokens with certain values.
My only points is that tokens are dynamic and should be retrieved from a file.

So it would be something like this:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

tasks.register('demoPlaceholders', Copy)  {
    from 'config-sets'
    into 'config-sets'
    include '**/*.template'
    rename '(.+).template', '$1'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens:"placeholders.txt")
    filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Basically I'm trying to do the same that I had in ant with the replace tasks using parameter replacefilterfile
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Any idea how this can be done?
at the moment it's simply not replacing anything but is doing everything else I need, just not sure how to apply the replaceToken aspect

I could not find a duplicate for this question, if it was just failing at google from my part I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a better answer, but this seemed to work for me:

```
ext {
    placeholderFile = "dummy/placeholders.txt"
    filterTokens = getFilterTokens()
}

Map<String, String> getFilterTokens () {
    Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>()
    new File(project.ext.placeholderFile.toString()).eachLine {
        if (it.contains("@")) {
            String[] split = it.split("=")
            String key = split[0].replaceAll("@","")
            String value = split[1]
            tokens.put(key, value)
        }
    }
    return tokens
}

import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

tasks.register('demoPlaceholders', Copy)  {
    from 'config-sets'
    into 'config-sets'
    include '**/*.template'
    rename '(.+).template', '$1'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens:project.ext.filterTokens)
    filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'
}
```